# Why is phenol more acidic than an alcohol but less reactive as an alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I understand why phenol is more acidic than ethanol but is less reactive? 
Eg: why unlike ethanol it can't react with a carboxylic acid?

Comment: It can and does react with carboxylic acids to form phenol esters, but as the phenoxide ion is stable and easily formed it is a good leaving group. Phenol  esters are activated, hydrolyse readily and are sometimes used as acylating agents, example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentafluorophenyl_esters

Comment: There are no more reactive or less reactive things. Also, somewhat in contradiction with the previous, I feel the need to say that phenol is in fact more reactive.

Comment: Quite, phenol is more reactive as a nucleophile than alcohols

Comment: I think it phenol is a poorer nucleophile than an alcohol because the unshared electron pair is delocalized into the benzene ring. These reactions are a delicate balance of base strength, nucleophilicity and leaving group. I have wondered if a simple ester could be transesterified with a an excess of phenoxide ion or if phenoxide is just too good a leaving group.